# Why am I receiving more Windows updates then announced in the Security Bulletin for September 2013?

Tags: windows, updates

In this image you can see that Windows tries to update more than they announced in the [Security Bulletin for September 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityBulletinSummaries/2013/ms13-sep?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

[image: screencap]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are security updates and are aptly listed in Microsofts security bulletins.

You wont see general updates for solitare or free cell in that section.

FWIW, I found that wearing my tin foil hat protects my PC more effeciantly than installing updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Yeah, tin foil might help... It's not that I am getting paranoid. But NSA story made me think that it is time to get a better understanding of my computer. Computers are not only vulnerable to intelligence services, but also to criminals etc. So when I heard in the news that there are 13 updates for September 2013, it made me think when I saw that my computer had 22 updates.

Answer (score 0):

record the updates on your wireshark network tap and send it to analyse with all your keys. Do you have signing key at your end? If not then low chance to figure out anything. Just left a trust.